# hibernate select subquery in from clause

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have this query:

```sql
SELECT
    DATE(t.trade_date) AS tradeDate,
    a.basic  ,
    b.total
FROM
    transaction t
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            DATE(trade_date) AS date,
            COUNT(transaction.id) AS basic
        FROM
            transaction,
            account
        WHERE
            transaction.account = account.id 
            and account.country='BE' 
            and trader_id in ('M8', 'M5')
        GROUP BY
            DATE(trade_date)
        ORDER BY
            date desc
    ) a ON a.date = DATE(t.trade_date)
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            DATE(trade_date) AS date,
            COUNT(transaction.id) AS total
        FROM
            transaction,
            account
        WHERE
            transaction.account = account.id 
            and account.country='BE' 
        GROUP BY
            DATE(trade_date)
        ORDER BY
            date desc
    ) b ON b.date = DATE(t.trade_date)
WHERE 
    t.trade_date is not null
GROUP BY
    DATE(t.trade_date)
ORDER BY 
    t.trade_date desc
```

However, hibernate does not support subqueries in FROM-clauses.
I don't have a clue on how to rewrite this to work correctly.

The calling java code I use is (where `sql` is a valid java string based on the one above):

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
public List<Object[]> getTotalAndBasicTransactionsCountry(String country, List traders){
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql, Object[].class)
                .setParameter("country", country)
                .setParameter("traders",traders);

return query.getResultList();
}
```

When using this code, I get the following error:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: [Ljava.lang.Object

Comment: Do you use native `SQLQuery` and it doesn't work?

Comment: see my edit to know how I use it

Comment: it's not subquery problem. you're trying extract `Object[]` and hibernate tells you about unknown entity

Comment: trying a fix as I read this. it is building.